# Protect PHP source code

Tags: php, linux, windows

due to bad internet bandwidth in my country, the client wishes for me to install my PHP/MySQL application on his Windows server or a Linux server.

What is the best way to protect the source code? Or the folder where the PHP source code resides. The client should be able to use the rest of the server freely.

Thank you.
Cyril

Comment: what do you want to protect it from? are you saying client should not be able to read the code, or execute it, or something else?

Comment: http://www.zend.com/en/products/guard/ ???

Comment: Protect it from copying, modifying and reading. The client should only execute the php files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to protect your php code is imho http://www.ioncube.com/

I would not recommend Zend Guard, because some tools exists which can recompile (not perfect) the compiled php code.

PHP Encode is also a bad idea, because it slows down your php code way more than other encoder.

Comment: I thought about ZendGuard and others, but I read either there will be a problem with the code, or it will slow down or it can be decompiled. That's why I was thinking of a password protected folder on an NTFS disk.

Comment: It's true, that with Zend Guard you can have issues, most based on unsupported php versions. Thats why we use ionCube - no problems and no performance issues. The only thing that could happen is, when you upload your encoded files as plain instead of binary, that can causes issues.

Answer (score 3):

you could use a code obfuscator

this is an [example](http://www.phpencode.org/)

though (with great difficulty) the code could be re-converted, but at least make the code more difficult to read

**example 1**

```
<?php
    echo phpinfo();
?>
```

would turn into something like this

```
<?php $XnNhAWEnhoiqwciqpoHH=file(__FILE__);eval(base64_decode("aWYoIWZ1bmN0aW9uX2V4aXN0cygiWWl1bklVWTc2YkJodWhOWUlPOCIpKXtmdW5jdGlvbiBZaXVuSVVZNzZiQmh1aE5ZSU84KCRnLCRiPTApeyRhPWltcGxvZGUoIlxuIiwkZyk7JGQ9YXJyYXkoNjU1LDIzNiw0MCk7aWYoJGI9PTApICRmPXN1YnN0cigkYSwkZFswXSwkZFsxXSk7ZWxzZWlmKCRiPT0xKSAkZj1zdWJzdHIoJGEsJGRbMF0rJGRbMV0sJGRbMl0pO2Vsc2UgJGY9dHJpbShzdWJzdHIoJGEsJGRbMF0rJGRbMV0rJGRbMl0pKTtyZXR1cm4oJGYpO319"));eval(base64_decode(YiunIUY76bBhuhNYIO8($XnNhAWEnhoiqwciqpoHH)));eval(ZsldkfhGYU87iyihdfsow(YiunIUY76bBhuhNYIO8($XnNhAWEnhoiqwciqpoHH,2),YiunIUY76bBhuhNYIO8($XnNhAWEnhoiqwciqpoHH,1)));__halt_compiler();aWYoIWZ1bmN0aW9uX2V4aXN0cygiWnNsZGtmaEdZVTg3aXlpaGRmc293Iikpe2Z1bmN0aW9uIFpzbGRrZmhHWVU4N2l5aWhkZnNvdygkYSwkaCl7aWYoJGg9PXNoYTEoJGEpKXtyZXR1cm4oZ3ppbmZsYXRlKGJhc2U2NF9kZWNvZGUoJGEpKSk7fWVsc2V7ZWNobygiRXJyb3I6IEZpbGUgTW9kaWZpZWQiKTt9fX0=684ec3cc57884cf14d34c372f3ab886384a059a3S03OyFcoyCjIzEvL19C0BgA=
```

**example 2**

```
<?php
for( $i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++ ) {
    echo( '5x'.$i.'='.(string)($i*5)."\n" );
}
?>
```

would turn into something like this

```
<?php $XnNhAWEnhoiqwciqpoHH=file(__FILE__);eval(base64_decode("aWYoIWZ1bmN0aW9uX2V4aXN0cygiWWl1bklVWTc2YkJodWhOWUlPOCIpKXtmdW5jdGlvbiBZaXVuSVVZNzZiQmh1aE5ZSU84KCRnLCRiPTApeyRhPWltcGxvZGUoIlxuIiwkZyk7JGQ9YXJyYXkoNjU1LDIzNiw0MCk7aWYoJGI9PTApICRmPXN1YnN0cigkYSwkZFswXSwkZFsxXSk7ZWxzZWlmKCRiPT0xKSAkZj1zdWJzdHIoJGEsJGRbMF0rJGRbMV0sJGRbMl0pO2Vsc2UgJGY9dHJpbShzdWJzdHIoJGEsJGRbMF0rJGRbMV0rJGRbMl0pKTtyZXR1cm4oJGYpO319"));eval(base64_decode(YiunIUY76bBhuhNYIO8($XnNhAWEnhoiqwciqpoHH)));eval(ZsldkfhGYU87iyihdfsow(YiunIUY76bBhuhNYIO8($XnNhAWEnhoiqwciqpoHH,2),YiunIUY76bBhuhNYIO8($XnNhAWEnhoiqwciqpoHH,1)));__halt_compiler();aWYoIWZ1bmN0aW9uX2V4aXN0cygiWnNsZGtmaEdZVTg3aXlpaGRmc293Iikpe2Z1bmN0aW9uIFpzbGRrZmhHWVU4N2l5aWhkZnNvdygkYSwkaCl7aWYoJGg9PXNoYTEoJGEpKXtyZXR1cm4oZ3ppbmZsYXRlKGJhc2U2NF9kZWNvZGUoJGEpKSk7fWVsc2V7ZWNobygiRXJyb3I6IEZpbGUgTW9kaWZpZWQiKTt9fX0=677f209731e728fdbcbec2b1e7f962f8042b6d7aS8sv0lBQyVSwVTC0BtE2QIYBiKWtraCpUM3LlZqcka+hoGRaoaSnkqmnZKukp1FcUpSZl66poZKpZaqppxSTp6Sgac3LVQsA
```

Answer (score 1):

You can obfuscate the php code online obfuscator/encoder [like this](https://encrypt.knicode.com/en) This tool protects code with powerful techniques, easier to rewrite than decode.

Answer (score 0):

You can obfuscate the php files on the server for extra protection. Obfuscation makes it more difficult for an attacker to understand your code, if he eventually gets in. Remember to keep an un-obfuscated back-up of your files.

Check Out
[Zend Guard](http://www.zend.com/en/products/guard/)